# Is there any Hadith that says anything about the Cross (Christianity)?

Tags: hadith, source-identification

I'm just wondering because I read someone saying there is a Hadith saying that the Prophet (p.b.u.h) did not accept the cross.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Bismillah.

Indeed, there are a few Hadiths that mention how the Prophet (PBUH) would deal with seeing the cross, or how one should deal with when seeing it.

> Al-Bukhaari narrated in his Saheeh from ‘Aa’ishah (may Allaah be
>   pleased with her) that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be
>   upon him) would never leave anything in his house on which there were
>   any crosses without erasing them or – according to another report
>   –cutting them out.

Therefore, whenever the Prophet (PBUH) would see the cross, he would never leave it unless blotting it out, or cutting it out if it was still visible after blotting it out, because the cross is something that is worshipped instead of Allah.

There is also a Hadith that mentions what one should do should he encounter a cross:

> “Whoever among you sees an evil action (munkar), let him change it
>   with his hand [by taking action], and if he cannot, then with his
>   tongue [by speaking out], and if he cannot, then with his heart [by
>   feeling that it is wrong], and that is the weakest of faith.”
>   (Narrated by Muslim).

Therefore, there are three main steps to follow (hand, tongue, heart) when someone sees such an evil act.

Finally:

> Muslim also narrated that Abu’l-Hayaaj al-Asadi said: “ ‘Ali (may
>   Allaah be pleased with him) said to me: ‘Shall I not send you on the
>   same mission that the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of
>   Allaah be upon him) sent me? Do not leave any image without blotting
>   it out and do not leave any built-up grave without levelling it.’”

Comment: You are very welcome! Your questions makes us all learn :)

Comment: "in his house on which there were any crosses without erasing them" - this is mistranslated and doesn't mention anything about "crosses" in Arabic.

Th actual translation would be untying knots.

Comment: Also, there is hadeeth that says when 'Isa (Jesus) (AS) will return to earth, he will be a just ruler. He will break the crosses and kill the swines, and will abolish Jizya.

Comment: you didn't provide any reference number to these hadiths